# Two table inserts retaining same ID for a ForeignKey using Webmatrix, Bootstrap, Html, and SQL

Tags: c#, html, sql, razor, webmatrix

I am working in visual studio with a database that has many tables.
I have a html bootstrap form which allows a user to input various fields and those fields must be inserted back into my database.

The insert statements work but not as expected. When I run "SELECT * From Storage FULL OUTER JOIN Cars ON Storage.carID = Car.carID". It shows two rows. One row has all NULL values for car except for carID/Name/Model and storage is the exact opposite.

I've tried playing around with a few ideas including webmatrix's GetLastInsertID() function but no luck. I'm a novice at this. Any help would be great!

See insert statements below...

```html
@{
  var db = Database.Open("DB Name");

  if (IsPost)
  {
      var inSql = "INSERT INTO Storage (location, GPS) VALUES (@0, @1)";

      var data = db.QueryValue(inSql,
              Request.Form["location"],
              Request.Form["gps"],

      var inCarSql = "INSERT INTO Cars (carName, modelName) VALUES (@0, @1)";

          var bData = db.QueryValue(inCarSql,
              Request.Form["carName"],
              Request.Form["modelName"]);           
  }
}
```

Comment: Neither of those commands insert a `CarId` value so not sure what you expected. Is it an `IDENTITY` column? Perhaps you need something like `INSERT INTO Cars (carName, modelName) VALUES (@0, @1); INSERT INTO Storage (carID, location, GPS) VALUES (SCOPEIDENTITY(), @2, @3)`

Comment: But then how come when I query both Cars and Storage the Cars table has a carID, carName, carModel?

FYI carID is the PK in Cars and the FK in Storage.

Comment: So how do you expect the FK to get into the table, you are not inserting it currently. Like I said, you need to take the `CarID` from `Cars` and use it in the other insert

Comment: Okay I will give that a try. 
But I am then unsure how I go about merging `var data = db.QueryValue(inSql,` and `var bData = db.QueryValue(inCarSql,` together if I do my INSERT statement as you've advised.

Comment: One multiline SQL batch, with two `INSERT` statements (as mentioned above), and pass in all four parameters at once